# Webmin MySQL Error on starting

Tags: mysql, webmin

Firstly, I must say that I have not used these tools in the past so linux commands are not familiar to me.

Backstory:
On my Webmin server, I have been trying to get a Drupal Installation to work. I changed a parameter on the MySQL module and now the MySQL will not start.

Current Situation: 
When I click "Start MySQL Server" I receive the follow:

> Failed to start database : Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start 
>   mariadb.service Job for mariadb.service failed because the control
>   process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mariadb.service"
>   and "journalctl -xe" for details.

I've search around this, and most people recommend to reinstall MariaDB. 
I connected to the server with putty to get some more information

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-08-01 16:29:00 UTC; 7min ago
  Process: 22851 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-wait-ready $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 22850 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 22823 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 22850 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 01 16:28:57 li172-89.members.linode.com systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Aug 01 16:28:57 li172-89.members.linode.com mysqld_safe[22850]: 170801 16:28:57 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'.
Aug 01 16:28:57 li172-89.members.linode.com mysqld_safe[22850]: 170801 16:28:57 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Aug 01 16:29:00 li172-89.members.linode.com systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 01 16:29:00 li172-89.members.linode.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Aug 01 16:29:00 li172-89.members.linode.com systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Aug 01 16:29:00 li172-89.members.linode.com systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
[root@li172-89 ~]#
```

I gather that this means Mariadb wont even start so I should probably reinstall it. I did try to simply use a defaul my.cnf but that didn't really do anything. 
**Ideally, I do not want to lose any of the databases I have**.

What should I do? Should I reinstall Mariadb? Is there a suitable guide that lists the commands? Could I install Mariadb but to another folder? 
What is the best course of action at this point?

Comment: Can you get more info for the lines ending with `...`?  Especially the 5 lines **before** the `mariadb.service failed` message. Append the updated information for those lines to the question.

Comment: Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

Comment: I updated the original post with the full log, I hope this can provide more clarity